# JSF 2 dynamic ui:include not working from 2.1.7 to 2.1.9

Tags: dynamic, jsf-2, include, state, save

I have a JSF 2/CDI webapp that dynamically configures some specific pages of the administration. It uses a bean to decide which page to include:

```
<ui:include src="#{myBean.myDynamicPath}"/>
```

In order to have it working, I've added the pages where I'm using it into the javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS context param and everything was working until I've updated the JSF libraries from 2.1.7 to 2.1.9 (and it has the same problem with the latest one).

When I try to execute some action on the page I get a long exception:

```
Oct 18, 2012 6:14:10 PM com.sun.faces.util.Util checkIdUniqueness
SEVERE: JSF1007: Duplicate component ID tabs:imagesListForm:imagesListDG:j_idt55 found in view.
Oct 18, 2012 6:14:10 PM com.sun.faces.util.Util checkIdUniqueness
SEVERE: +id: j_id1
    type: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@4478de9f
        +id: javax_faces_location_HEAD

        ... (all the view tree here) ...

Oct 18, 2012 6:14:10 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/admin/objects/edit.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID tabs:imagesListForm:imagesListDG:j_idt55 has already been found in the view.
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:842)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:826)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:826)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:826)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:826)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:826)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:826)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:826)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:826)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:826)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:826)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletFullStateManagementStrategy.saveView(FaceletFullStateManagementStrategy.java:686)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:89)
    at javax.faces.application.StateManager.getViewState(StateManager.java:553)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderState(PartialViewContextImpl.java:417)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:300)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:981)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at uk.co.novaware.core.cdi.scope.ConversationFilter.doFilter(ConversationFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at uk.co.novaware.core.cdi.scope.ConversationFilter.doFilter(ConversationFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Has the way how ui:include works been changed? Anyone has some idea to have it working again? I need to update JSF libraries.

Comment: Can you post relevant code rendering the component "tabs:imagesListForm:imagesListDG:j_idt55"?

Comment: Hello @Ravi, it doesn't matter which code I put, it wouldn't work anyway, in that case it is a p:dataTable inside an h:form inside a p:tab inside a p:tabView but I've tried also adding simple components and the result is the same...

Comment: @Ravi No, and I've checked that all the ids are unique...also if I use JSF 2.1.7 it works properly...

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix :Try stating ID values for all the elements. And make sure the IDs are unique.

You can check for the IDs generated in the resulting html to determine which tag is causing the issue.